# what's that protruding when I move the rig?

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

is it that rigify is not detecting the inside faces or what... I've seen that deleting the inside faces works but I doubt that's the solution.

Comment: I suggest uploading your blend file, it's hard to pin down an issue like this just from a screenshot.  It may have something to do with your mesh's rigging weight paints/vertex groups.

Comment: Not sure this is a rigify issue, could be a weighting issue.  Are the  _"inside faces"_  a mesh within the outer skin? Could  you please provide a wireframe or edit mode image of such.

Comment: how do I upload a bleder file here so you can look at it?

Comment: its one mesh... I just applied a solidify modifier